# CloudFormation parametes limit exceeded

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have exceeded parameters limit in cloudformation template.Is there any way that I can keep all parameters in s3 as a file and include to my template

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are saying you have an **AWS CloudFormation template** that has a number of parameters, and you are unable to create the stack because there are too many parameters.

The [CloudFormation limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) documentation says:

> Maximum number of parameters that you can declare in your AWS CloudFormation template: **60 parameters**
>
> To specify more parameters, you can use mappings or lists in order to assign multiple values to a single parameter.

This advice is suggested that some parameters could be combined and passed through as one parameter (a list). Alternatively, if multiple values are related to each other you could create a **mapping** such that one input value allows multiple values to be retrieved via a lookup.

Worst case, you could use an AWS Lambda function as a **Custom Resource** to perform additional logic and return values -- these values could be retrieved from an object in Amazon S3 or through some other processing.

Also, it is normally recommended to **avoid having large, complex templates**. Instead, break it into smaller templates and call [nested templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/use-nested-stacks-to-create-reusable-templates-and-support-role-specialization/). This makes it easier maintain and debug.

Answer (score 0):

it appeared that the limit for the number of parameters has been increased to 200 as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html?pg=fq&sec=lr)